# Why don't T1 instances show up in amazon docs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to launch a T1 instance
Why don't T1 instances show up in amazon docs.
This is the page I am refering to where all types are listed
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
But I can't find t1 there inspite of the fact i have active t1 host running.
So I don't think its deprecated or something.
Amazon even has a page on their differences https://cloudacademy.com/blog/amazon-ec2-t2-instances-chip-off-the-old-t1-micro-block/

It comes as disabled whhen dropdown changed to all generations:

[image]

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but a documentation question, and is off-topic. That said, t1 *has* been deprecated for t2, and is documented as such.

Comment: then how was my T1 instance launched. I am talking about just a week back when ELB auto launched it

Comment: *Deprecated.*  Not discontinued. As documented. Just search "ec2 t1".

Comment: So where do I find it to launch manually?

Comment: When I change the generation drop down I can see T1 but it shows instance type disabled, so it seems it can't be launched manually.

Comment: I guess you can't launch new ones then. Again: off topic for here. Maybe contact support?

Comment: @ishandutta2007. As a general rule, you will pay more for a deprecated instance type. Sort of Amazon's way of pushing you to use current generation products. The reason that older instance types still exist is that you can lose customers by dropping support for systems that are in production (enterprise style support policies). This way customers can take their time (and pay for it) until they can move to the current generation.

Answer (score 1):

The T1 instance type is [listed in the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html), but it is a [previous Generation Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/previous-generation/).

To reduce confusion, older generation instance types are frequently shown in separate listings.

When a new region or availability zone comes online, they will often **not** contain any previous-generation instances. This means that some regions or AZs will not have the T1 instance family.

If you wish to use a T1 instance, filter the Instance Type page in the EC2 launch wizard to show **All generations**:

[image: Filter instance type]

Also, please note that T1 instances only support **PV** (Paravirtualization) AMIs, and do not support **HVM** (Hardware Virtual Machine) AMIs. So, in the launch wizard, be sure to select an AMI that shows a type of PV:

[image: PV]

Comment: For me it comes as disabled whhen dropdown changed to all generations, question updated with screenshot

Comment: If you point to the "no-entry" symbol in the first column, it will explain to you that you need to use an AMI that is of type **PV**, as mentioned in my answer. Go back to the previous screen (where you select an AMI) and select one marked as PV.